# SQL Server replication: Need to remove articles from the publication

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I am replicating the data from the Database1 on Server1 to respectively, Database2 on Server2.

Now, the requirement is to remove certain tables form being replicated - so I will remove them from the Publication.
I have many articles, so am doing it using script and cursor .. but for simplicity, I will use example of one:

So, I am following this routine, but have a question:
**Questions are:**  Is there anywhere in the below, before or after where I need to

- Stop / start snapshot agent?
- Stop / start log reader agent?
- Stop / start distribution agent?

If I do have to start / stop respective agent jobs, do I do it for every article or I can do it before (stop) and after (start) the cursor loop where each article is individually dropped?

The routine followed is

```
USE Database 1
 SELECT @publicationName = name
 FROM dbo.syspublications sp


-- Change the allow_anonymous property of the publication to FALSE
   EXEC sp_changepublication
    @publication = @publicationName,
    @property = N'allow_anonymous',
    @value = 'FALSE'

    -- Next, disable Change immediate_sync
     EXEC sp_changepublication
     @publication = @publicationName,
     @property = N'immediate_sync',
     @value = 'FALSE'
```

Assuming, the following is used in the cursor-loop, and there is a variable for @articleName

```
SELECT articleName 
FROM (
    SELECT sp.pubid, sp.name as 'publicationName', sp.description, sa.artid, 
  sa.name as 'articleName', sa.dest_table, sa.schema_option
    FROM dbo.syspublications sp
    INNER JOIN dbo.sysarticles sa
    ON sp.pubid=sa.pubid
) arts
WHERE articleName = '<TheArticleName>' --In reality it will be 'like '%%'

    -- Must drop subscription first
    EXEC sp_dropsubscription 
        @publication = @publicationName, 
        @article = @articleName,-- obtained from above
        @subscriber = 'Server 2'

    -- Drop the transactional article.
    EXEC sp_droparticle 
      @publication = @publicationName, 
      @article = @articleName,
      @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1;

-- Next, Enable Change immediate_sync
EXEC sp_changepublication
@publication = @publicationName,
@property = N'immediate_sync',
@value = 'TRUE'

-- Change the allow_anonymous property of the publication to TRUE
EXEC sp_changepublication
@publication = @publicationName,
@property = N'allow_anonymous',
@value = 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 0):

> SQL Server replication: Need to remove articles from the publication

...

> Questions are: Is there anywhere in the below, before or after where I need to
>
> - Stop / start snapshot agent?
> - Stop / start log reader agent?
> - Stop / start distribution agent?

If you're **only** removing Articles from the Publication (not actually removing whole Subscriptions) then the answer should be no to each of these questions.

To be honest, I personally prefer using the UI in SSMS to manage Replication. It's the kind of thing that trying to script it yourself is more complicated and one of the few areas the SSMS UI does a pretty good job. It's the quicker / simpler route.

The fact your script has `EXEC sp_dropsubscription` scares me if your intentions are, again, only to remove specific Articles from the Publication (but you want to keep the Subscribers still in place for the other Articles being Published). I do realize you are parameterizing it to specific Articles, but in an automated way, if there was a bug in the script, I'd still be weary of inadvertently dropping the whole Subscriber.

Comment: Thank you, for the input.  The issue with the SSMS is that I have many tables .. as an example without getting into details as of why, 238 tables I may need to remove in one case.   And I have 4 databases being replicated. It is somewhat tedious job to do if I have to do it more than once.

Also, eventually, I may need to be adding articles to publication.....

Comment: @DmitriyRyabin You're removing 238 tables out of how many Articles total?

Comment: Not tables.  i am sorry .. there are 238 articles to be removed.  Total number of articles in a publication maybe twice more